# Router servlet for webservice project

Tags: http, maven, web, websphere

In my recent project i started using maven , instead of depending on RAD to deploy and build ear, i have been coming across little things why to use , which one is best..

My question here is , below code i copied form web.xml and it us com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet servlet by ibm to route http request to  web services, is there any servlet present from java that can replace the above one , we dont want our ear generation should be dependent on specific application server

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>com.test.HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>com.test.HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorldService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The Servlet that you're seeing in the `web.xml` is an IBM-proprietary Servlet that routes HTTP requests to Web Services and, as far as I can tell, if you're running WAS 7.0 onwards you don't need it. You can simply use JAX-WS to annotate your Web Service class.

**EDIT** as per OP's comment

As you're using WAS 8.5, you have JavaEE 6.0 at your disposal. You don't need any router project anymore. IBM's proprietary router was needed in previous versions of WAS in order to route HTTP requests to Web Services and/or EJBs; however, with JavaEE 6.0, you can use JAX-WS in order to automatically intercept HTTP requests by Web Service classes as well as EJBs.

If you have a "router" project, you can safely throw it away.

Comment: Thank you for the replay..  Isaac the information you have given i really worth for me ... Going more details.. We are using websphere 8.5. To generate ear of the ejb- web services do we need web router project?. We are using the web router project to generate ear .. Using annotation .. Is the same process to generate ear or without web router project can we generate ear?  Please let me know if i am confusing ..thank you

Comment: Isaac .. This information is really great with this i can throw away almost more than 10 projects.. Thanks a lot ..

Comment: @Dhairya less is always more. Throw them away!

Comment: Hi Isaac ,can you give any reference point  ,i am working on POC, i need to see how it works , i was looking on google for that , but not really getting detailed information

Comment: Created Web service project without Web router project